# PhoneGap - Can't Find variable

Tags: javascript, function, variables, cordova, slideshow

So I made a simple slideshow in js to display a photogalery in a page, the problem is that whenever I try the slideshow the console shows me the error

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: next

This is my code:

slideshow js code:

```
    <script>
var myImage= new Array(); 
myImage[0]="1.jpg";       
myImage[1]="2.jpg";
myImage[2]="3.jpg";
myImage[3]="4.jpg";
myImage[4]="5.jpg";
myImage[5]="6.jpg"; 
myImage[6]="7.jpg"; 
myImage[7]="8.jpg"; 
myImage[8]="9.jpg"; 
myImage[9]="10.jpg"; 
myImage[10]="11.jpg"; 
myImage[11]="12.jpg";   

var ImageCnt = 0;

function next(){
    ImageCnt++;
    document.getElementById("whiteBox").style.background = 'url(' + myImage[ImageCnt] + ')';
  }
function previous(){
    ImageCnt--;
    document.getElementById("whiteBox").style.background = 'url(' + myImage[ImageCnt] + ')';
  }
</script>
```

html body code:

```
<div data-role="content">
    <div id="whiteBox"></div>
    <a href="#" onclick="next();return false;"><img src="next.png"/></a>
    <a href="#" onclick="previous();return false;"><</a>
    </div>
```

I searched on the internet and found many similiar situations, but I could not find the solution.

Comment: Can you post all of your HTML?  This code basically works for me in a test Phonegap application.  Also, what do you mean by console?  Do you mean logcat output?

Answer (score 1):

Have you attemped to try call it in console?

Use Google chrome press CTRL+SHIFT+J and type in `next();`

Or try this;

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:next();"><img src="next.png"/></a>
```

Comment: The script works if I open the website with the browser, but when I run it with the emulator i get the error ReferenceError: Can't find variable: next

Comment: Maybe its just a phonegap bug? or you have a next variable?

Comment: Before I made this js script, I made a simple html navmenu '<div data-role="navmenu">' with '<ul><li><a href="#" OnClick="function show();"></a></li></ul>' and made a script that would made a submenu visible by clicking in '<a>' and it showd me the same thing..., the script was 'function show(){ $(".show").css("visibility", "visible")}' and it showed me the error ReferenceError. Can't find variable show. Maybe I need to make the function by other way because phonegap seems not to be working with simple js functions